# Close QGIS plugin window event

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm creating a QGIS Python plugin and i want to execute some code after hitting the close button 'X'.
I've added the code bellow to init function and the closeEvent function but still not working

```
self.dlg.closeEvent = self.closeEvent
```

Comment: This isn't really a QGIS question - you're better off asking on https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I think it is because the window is displayed in qgis so it's managed by qgis

Comment: Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/q/14834494/4699904

Answer (score 1):

```
dialog.rejected.connect(self.some_function)
```

or (depends on what type of dialog you are working)

```
dialog.parent().rejected.connect(self.some_function)
```